# How to hide PrimeNG colorpicker overlay?

Tags: styles, primeng, color-picker

Does anyone have an idea on how to create colorpickers overlay style (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/colorpicker) with predefined colors but on click keep the overlay hidden and just apply the predefined color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through a `ViewChild` reference, you can manipulate your colorpicker by invoking [`togglePanel`](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/colorpicker/colorpicker.ts#L313) method in order to close it once you have selected a color.

**HTML**

```
<p-colorPicker #myColorPicker [(ngModel)]="color" (onChange)="onColorSelected()"></p-colorPicker>
```

**TS**

```
color = '#1976D2';

@ViewChild('myColorPicker') myColorPicker: ColorPicker;
```

and

```
onColorSelected() {
  this.myColorPicker.togglePanel();
}
```

Comment: works thx! and if I wanted to have multiple colorpickers without having to hardcode them or at least don't have to duplicate onColorSelected? ViewChildren does not hide  the overlay or maybe Im missing something here: @ViewChildren(ColorPicker) colourPickers: QueryList<ColorPicker>; ... and in onColourSelected:  this.colourPickers.find((item, index, array) => (index === i)); ...